# multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar],overflow in conversion from 'int' to 'char',ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*'

Tags: c++

Here is my string.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char name_str = 'anaa';
    char *name = "John";
    return 0;
}
```

It's showing some warning in my terminal those are:-

```
string.cpp:6:21: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
 char name_str = 'anaa';
                 ^~~~~~ 
string.cpp: In function 'int main(int, const char**)':
string.cpp:6:21: warning: overflow in conversion from 'int' to 'char' changes value from 
 '1634623841' to ''a'' [-Woverflow]
string.cpp:7:18: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [- 
 Wwrite-strings]
 char *name = "John";
              ^~~~~~
```

Please anyone help me to understand these warnings!!!
I have seen the same type of questions are already been asked on the stack-overflow but there was not any detail explanation why it happened?

Comment: String literals are enclosed in `"` double quotes.

Comment: `const char *name` will fix the second warning. As for the first one - `char` is a single character, not a string. Attempting to put more than one character in single quotes is not illegal per se, but does funky things.

Comment: `char` field can accept only a single character. such as `a` or `b` and cannot accept a string of characters like you showed in line no. 6. To accept a string of characters use the `std::string` container or `const char*`.

Comment: If you need a mutable char array with the contents of a string literal, you need to do `char name[] = "John";`, but perhaps you don't need the data to be modifiable...

Comment: I want to extend what @Mubin says: use only `std::string`. If you're learning C++, learn C++. Although C++ supports the other, it's C legacy. Many mistakes have been made (and bugs caused) by misusing `char*`.

Answer (score 1):

- `'anaa'` is not a character, so you can't assign it to a `char` type. It's also not a string(`"anaa"` is one)
- `"John"` is a string constant, so you have to declare `name` as `const char *name = "John"`